# How to get email address entered by user when entering into my vue js application?

Tags: vue.js, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I have used adal.js to enable signing in to my vue js application through the azure active directory. I however want to restrict the app to only a few users within that directory. Now, I want to know the email address entered by the user immediately after he hits enter, so that I can then check whether I should allow him access or not- i.e. take him to the home page if yes, and deny access if no.

I have tried the following, but am unable to get auth._user. It shows null.

```
import * as AuthenticationContext from 'adal-angular/lib/adal';

const config = {
    tenant: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:1337',
    cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage'
};

export default {
    authenticationContext: null,

    initialize() {

        this.authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);
        var auth = this.authenticationContext;

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            if (auth.isCallback(window.location.hash) || window.self !== window.top) {
                // redirect to the location specified in the url params.
                auth.handleWindowCallback();
            } else {

                // try pull the user out of local storage
                let user = auth.getCachedUser();

                if (user) {
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    // no user at all - go sign in.
                    this.signIn();
                }
            }
        });


    },
    /**
   * @return {Promise.<String>} A promise that resolves to an ADAL token for resource access
   */
    acquireToken() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.authenticationContext.acquireToken('https://Atkins.onmicrosoft.com/624c09d9-0646-4699-83b3-d8abdf1f5c47', (error, token) => {
                if (error || !token) {
                    return reject(error);
                } else {
                    return resolve(token);
                }
            });
        });
    },
    /**
     * Issue an interactive authentication request for the current user and the api resource.
     */
    acquireTokenRedirect() {
        this.authenticationContext.acquireTokenRedirect('https://Atkins.onmicrosoft.com/624c09d9-0646-4699-83b3-d8abdf1f5c47');
    },
    /**
     * @return {Boolean} Indicates if there is a valid, non-expired access token present in localStorage.
     */
    isAuthenticated() {
        // getCachedToken will only return a valid, non-expired token.
        if (this.authenticationContext.getCachedToken(config.clientId)) { return true; }
        return false;
    },
    /**
   * @return {Object} An ADAL user profile object.
   */
    getUserProfile() {
        return this.authenticationContext.getCachedUser().profile;
    },
    signIn() {
        this.authenticationContext.login();
    },
    signOut() {
        this.authenticationContext.logOut();
    }

};
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why you are unable to get the user. Keep in mind though that the user restrictions need to be applied in the back-end. Any restrictions in the front-end can be removed by the user since the code is on their machine.

Comment: Wecome to StackOverflow! It's difficult to help with this questions, because there isn't enough code to reproduce (only) your issue. Can you include the minimum code needed to reproduce the issue you're experiencing? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more details.